# Python: No Traceback when Scraping Data into Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, urllib, xlsxwriter

I'm an inexperienced coder working in python. I wrote a script to automate a process where certain information would be ripped from a webpage and then copied, where it would be pasted into a new excel spreadsheet. I've written and executed the code, but the excel spreadsheet I've designated to receive the data is completely empty. Worst of all, there is no traceback error. Would you help me find the problem in my code? And how do you generally solve your own problems when not provided a traceback error?

```
import xlsxwriter, urllib.request, string


def main():

    #gets the URL for the expert page
open_sesame = urllib.request.urlopen('https://aries.case.com.pl/main_odczyt.php?strona=eksperci')
    #reads the expert page
readpage = open_sesame.read()
    #opens up a new file in excel
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('expert_book.xlsx')
    #adds worksheet to file
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    #initializing the variable used to move names and dates
    #in the excel spreadsheet
boxcoA = ""
boxcoB = ""
    #initializing expert attribute variables and lists
expert_name = ""
url_ticker = 0
name_ticker = 0
raw_list = []
url_list = []
name_list= []
date_list= []
    #this loop goes through and finds all the lines
    #that contain the expert URL and name and saves them to raw_list::
    #raw_list loop
for i in readpage:
    i = str(i)
    if i.startswith('<tr><td align=left><a href='):
        raw_list += i

    #this loop goes through the lines in raw list and extracts
    #the name of the expert, saving it to a list::
    #name_list loop
for n in raw_list:
    name_snip = n.split('target=_blank>','</a></td><')[1]
    name_list += name_snip
    #this loop fills a list with the dates the profiles were last updated::
    #date_list
for p in raw_list:
        url_snipoff = p[28:]
        url_snip = url_snipoff.split('"')[0]
        url_list += url_snip
        expert_url = 'https://aries.case.com.pl/'+url_list[url_ticker]
        open_expert = urllib2.openurl(expert_url)
        read_expert = open_expert.read()
        for i in read_expert:
            if i.startswith('<p align=left><small>Last update:'):
                update = i.split('Last update:','</small>')[1]
        open_expert.close()
        date_list += update

    #now that we have a list of expert names and a list of profile update dates
    #we can work on populating the excel spreadsheet


    #this operation will iterate just as long as the list is long
    #meaning that it will populate the excel spreadsheet
    #with all of our names and dates that we wanted
for z in raw_list:
    boxcoA = string('A',z)
    boxcoB = string('B',z)
    worksheet.write(boxcoA, name_list[z])
    worksheet.write(boxcoB, date_list[z])
workbook.close()
print('Operation Complete')


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of a traceback only means your code raises no exceptions. It does not mean your code is logically correct.

I would look for logic errors by adding print statements, or using a debugger such as [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb/).

One problem I notice with your code is that the first loop seems to presume that `i` is a line, whereas it is actually a character. You might find [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) more useful

Answer (score 0):

If there is no traceback then there is no error.

Most likely something has gone wrong with your scraping/parsing code and your `raw_list` or other arrays aren't populated.

Try print out the data that should be written to the worksheet in the last loop to see if there is any data to be written.

If you aren't writing data to the worksheet then it will be empty.

Comment: OK, that was a good hint. raw_list is empty, but I don't understand why. The startswith condition "<tr><td align=left><a href=" was copied straight out of the source code. Does the problem have to do with the way the urllib.request module reads the page?